# Java : write recursive function and check if one digit is even and the other not

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am struggling with an exercise I got.
I need to write a recursive function that checks if one digit is odd and the other one is even, it is need to toggle in any digit.

For example,

- 123 is true (3 is odd, 2 is even, 1 is odd)
- 1234 is also true
- 12354 is false (4 is even, 5 is odd and 3 is odd)

The digits must be alternating between even and odd.

If the number is only 1 digit you return true. All numbers are positive.

Below is the function I wrote,
and I can't find where my mistake is :/

```
//Assumption : num > 0
//this function will return if true or not if number is alternating
public static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num) {
    boolean flag;
    if(num < 10) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        flag =  isAlternatingNumber(num/10);
        int n = num% 10;
        if(num%10 % 2 == 0 && flag) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try casting `num` to `double` in `flag =  isAlternatingNumber(num/10);`. Also, `&&` should be `!=`.

Comment: What are the requirements to the accepted algorithm? E.g. time limit, memory usage limit, size of data, or mb any big-o complexity limits.

Answer (score 0):

This question can actually be *considered (and so tagged?) as algorithmic*. That would gravitate much more attention, interesting implementations, reactions, advices, etc.

Since OP provided very much close-to-right solution, any 1 correction leads to working algorithm. I just post possible evaluation of the idea of OP.

```
public static boolean isAlter(int num, boolean isPrevEven) 
{
    int next = (num - num % 10) / 10;
    boolean isCurrEven = num % 2 == 0;
    boolean isOk = (isCurrEven && !isPrevEven) || (!isCurrEven && isPrevEven);

    if (isOk) 
         return next == 0 || isAlter(next, isCurrEven);
    else return false;
}
```

And what is more interesting on this question is **what are the requirements to the accepted algorithm**? E.g. *time limit, memory usage limit, size of data*, or mb any big-o complexity limits.

Recursive algorithms most often can be rewritten in iterative way, which also often leads to time / memory consumption improvement. Yet, recursion is elegant, and if it does not contradict requirements or efficiency, nothing bad at all. Just remember to make correct *base cases*, so recursion does not go to infinity, which causes `StackOverflow` error.

PS: Should method accept only 1 argument, it is surely not an issue:

```
public boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num) 
{
    boolean isEven = num % 2 == 0;
    return isAlter(num, !isEven);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original function signature `public static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num)` cannot be changed, you can solve this problem by using a `recursive helper function` to add additional parameters to your recursive function.

Here is an example of how you might solve this problem by using a `recursive helper function`;

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println("123: " + isAlternatingNumber(123)); // true
    System.out.println("1234: " + isAlternatingNumber(1234)); // true
    System.out.println("12354: " + isAlternatingNumber(12354)); // false
  }
  
  // Original function with unmodified signature
  public static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num) {
    // Base case, returns true if num is only 1 digit
    if (num < 10) {
        return true;
    }
    
    /*
        + First argument; num with its first digit "sliced" (if num is 123, num / 10 is 12)
        + Second argument; Whether or not if the first digit of num is even (if num is 123,
        (num % 10) % 2 == 0 is false, as (num % 10) gives 3, and 3 % 2 is 1, as 3 is an odd number)
    */
    return findIfAlternating((num / 10), (num % 10) % 2 == 0);
  }

  /**
  * Recursive helper function to find if a given number is alternating
  * between odd and even (or vice versa) digits
  * @param num number to be checked, without its first digit
  * @param isCurrentDigitEven whether or not if the first digit of the number to be checked is even
  */
  public static boolean findIfAlternating(int num, boolean isCurrentDigitEven) {
    boolean isNextDigitEven = (num % 10) % 2 == 0;
    
    // Base case, returns true if the digits are alternating between odd and even
    if (num < 10) {
        return (isCurrentDigitEven ^ isNextDigitEven); // ^ is the XOR operator in Java, returns true if either one of the variables are true, and returns false if both variables are false or true
    }  
    
    return (isCurrentDigitEven ^ isNextDigitEven) && findIfAlternating((num / 10), isNextDigitEven);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the function I wrote, and I can't find where my mistake is

```java
flag =  isAlternatingNumber(num/10);
```

Method `isAlternatingNumber` keeps calling itself until `num` is less than 10 (ten).

If, for example, we initially call method `isAlternatingNumber` with the number 123, then there will be three calls to the method as follows:

```java
isAlternatingNumber(123);
isAlternatingNumber(12);
isAlternatingNumber(1);
```

The last call will return *true*.
Then, in the second last call, the method will continue, i.e. the following line will be executed:

```java
if(num%10 % 2 == 0 && flag)
```

Note that local variable `n` is never used so this line actually does not affect the value returned by method `isAlternatingNumber`:

```java
int n = num % 10;
```

As soon as `num` is an odd number, method `isAlternatingNumber` will return *false*. Then every recursive call will return *false*.

For the last two digits of the number to be alternating even/odd, either the number is even and the number divided by ten is odd or vice versa (unless the number is less than ten which is considered as "true"), i.e.

```java
(num % 2 == 0 && (num / 10) % 2 == 1) || (num % 2 == 1 && (num / 10) % 2 == 0) || num < 10
```

If the above expression returns true (and `num` is greater than ten), then repeat for `num / 10`.

```
public static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        int rem1 = num % 2;
        int rem2 = (num / 10) % 2;
        boolean flag = ((rem1 == 0 && rem2 == 1) || (rem1 == 1 && rem2 == 0));
        return flag && isAlternatingNumber(num / 10);
    }
}
```

`flag` is true if `rem1` and `rem2` do **not** have the same value.

```java
return flag && isAlternatingNumber(num / 10);
```

If `flag` is false, Java will not [recursively] call method `isAlternatingNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex to the rescue:

```
public static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num) {
    return !("" + num).matches(".*([02468]{2}|[13579]{2}).*");
}
```

Comment: Note: OP asked for recursive function

Answer (score 0):

For recursive solution it is enough to recursively check the last digits with `true/false` ets. On each recursion remove the last digit of the value.

```java
public static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num) {
    boolean lastDigitEven = num % 10 % 2 == 0;
    return isAlternatingNumber(num, lastDigitEven);
}

private static boolean isAlternatingNumber(int num, boolean expectedLastDigitEven) {
    if (num == 0)
        return true;

    boolean lastDigitEven = num % 10 % 2 == 0;

    if (lastDigitEven == expectedLastDigitEven)
        return isAlternatingNumber(num / 10, !lastDigitEven);

    return false;
}
```